# Convert every Uri to file

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

My activity gets a `shared intent`, possibly with media. 
Here is the `Activity` declaration :

```
<activity
        android:name=".name"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I extract the media using the following code :

```
Uri mediaUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```

Unfortunately the media comes in a `Uri` (Might be `content://` or any other)
I was wondering how apps like `Google Keep` for example, knows to convert all these Uri's to files, and how can I do it myself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering how apps like Google Keep for example, knows to convert all these Uri's to files

I have no idea why you think Google Keep will "convert all these Uri's to files".

A `Uri` is akin to a URL. It is an opaque handle to a remote resource that you can access via a stream in your app. In the case of a `Uri`, you use a `ContentResolver` to get that stream, rather than using some HTTP client API (e.g., `HttpUrlConnection`, OkHttp) to get a stream on the data represented by a Web URL.

Ideally, you just use the stream. If for some reason you *absolutely* have to have a file, use the stream to make a local copy of the data for your app, in a place that you designate, for which you have filesystem access. Once again, this is not significantly different than working with `http` or `https` URLs, where you cannot magically convert a URL into a file, other than by using a stream to download the content.

Bear in mind that a `Uri` does not have to point to a file, just as a URL does not have to point to a file. For example, the URL for this Web page most likely does not correspond to some file on a server somewhere. Instead, the Web page probably is generated by a Web app. The same thing holds true with a `Uri`. The `Uri` could be pointing to:

- a file that your app could conceivably access
- a file that your app cannot access, as you do not have rights to that location (e.g., internal storage of another app)
- a file that does not exist on the local device, but rather would need to be downloaded by the other app in response to some app asking for the content
- a file that is local but is stored encrypted and needs to be decrypted
- a file that is generated on the fly, just as this Web page is
- and so on

Hence, treat the `Uri` as a handle, get a stream on the content pointed to by that `Uri`, and do not worry about where that content actually comes from.

Comment: Thanks, Shouldn't there be any guarantee ill be able to access the file since it comes from `share` intent ? I need the file to create a `MimeMessage` and send an email with this file attached, can I do it without getting the physical file ?

Comment: @SagiLow: "Shouldn't there be any guarantee ill be able to access the file since it comes from share intent ?" -- no. Please re-read my answer, particularly the bulleted list. "can I do it without getting the physical file" -- as I wrote in my answer, If for some reason you absolutely have to have a file, use the stream to make a local copy of the data for your app, in a place that you designate, for which you have filesystem access.

Comment: Can you please share or point me to how I can check the accessibility  and get the stream out of the `Uri` ?

Comment: @SagiLow: Call `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver` to get the stream. You get a `ContentResolver` by calling `getContentResolver()` on any handy `Context`, such as an `Activity` or `Service`. You can then use standard Java I/O to read in that stream, not significantly differently than how you would read in the stream from `HttpURLConnection` for downloading a Web page.

Comment: Ill give it a shot. Thank you

Comment: CommonsWare you get better and better in explaining why there are uries and content resolvers. You know how reluctant i was a time ago about not being able to use the File class. But now you turned me on. Thanks.